# JAVA / MaskFormatter: Allow Placeholder Character

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I use the following code, to apply a MaskFormatter on my `JFormattedTextField` in order to make it accept IBANs (2 letters followed by 20 digits):

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("UU## #### #### #### #### ##");
formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
jFormattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter));
```

Whenever there's an empty space in that textfield, the placeholder character ('_') holds that place as intended. But once you focus a different textfield, the field will check if the String inside is valid, and reset it otherwise. However, I don't want it to change if it looks like this for example:

`AA00 11_1 2222 ____ 4444 5555 66`

In order to achieve that, I'd have to allow the placeholder character as a valid MaskCharacter in every position. Which would be achievable by copying the entire class and modifying `isValidCharacter()`, but that's dirty.

Is there a way to do something like?:

```
new MaskFormatter("[U^_][U^_][#^_][#^_] [#^_][#^_][#^_][#^_] [#^_][#^_][#^_][#^_] ...");
```

Or something like `formatter.allowCharacter('_')`

---

It does sort of work with "**** **** **** **** **** **", but that doesn't force the user to input valid characters at the given positions, so it's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Method `isValidCharacter()` looks for below methods for validation. I guess, Setting appropriate values for in the below method would be more than enough

```
formatter.setValidCharacters("")
formatter.setInvalidCharacters("")
```

Comment: Those decide what character the user can type in general - the actual isValidCharacter() (or whatever method deals with that) checks if a (valid) character is in the correct position... Which it isn't if not included in the mask.